# io-fabric-sdk-android_fabric/src does not exist

Tags: java, android, ios, eclipse, ant

I am trying to build android project from console using ant.

- python ./build_native.py (required for cocos2d-x)
- running android update project -p .
- ant debug

I have all setting and code right, since eclipse is able to make the apk.
when I run ant debug, following error is displayed:

> BUILD FAILED
>   /Users/avi/Downloads/android-sdk-macosx/tools/ant/build.xml:597: The following error occurred while executing this line:
>   /Users/avi/Downloads/android-sdk-macosx/tools/ant/build.xml:649: The following error occurred while executing this line:
>   /Users/avi/Downloads/android-sdk-macosx/tools/ant/build.xml:655: /Users/avi/Downloads/donkey/proj.android/kit-libs/io-fabric-sdk-android_fabric/src does not exist.